# How to make a sample from the empirical distribution function

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, statistics-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement the nonparametric bootstrapping on Python. It requires to take a sample, build an empirical distribution function from it and then to generate a bunch of samples from this edf. How can I do it?
In scipy I found only how to make your own distribution function if you know the exact formula describing it, but I have only an edf.

Comment: why do you need the EDF? you should just sample (with replacement) from your data, these will be your bootstrap samples

Answer (score 2):

The edf you get by sorting the samples:

```
N = samples.size
ss = np.sort(samples) # these are the x-values of the edf
                      # the y-values are 1/(2N), 3/(2N), 5/(2N) etc.
edf = lambda x: np.searchsorted(ss, x) / N
```

However, if you only want to resample then you simply draw from your sample with equal probability and replacement.

If this is too "steppy" for your liking, you can probably use some kind of interpolation to get a smooth distribution.

Comment: the EDF is by **definition** steppy !

Comment: @maxymoo Yes I know that. But typically one is not really interested in the edf for its own sake but as a device to estimate the "true" distribution. And one may have good reasons to assume that the true distribution is smooth. Also, depending on what you use your new samples for, sampling from a discrete distribution where the true distribution is smooth may well lead to artifacts.

Comment: this is interesting  ... do you often smooth your bootstraps?

Comment: @maxymoo Luckily, my day-to-day life doesn't require much statistics. Why, do you have any principled objections? I'm always happy to listen to superior knowledge.

Comment: lol "luckily" no i definitely don't have superior knowledge or any principled objections, i've learned something here, and will keep the smoothing trick in mind in future if i observe artefacts in my bootstraps.