# Sampling rows in data frame with an empirical probability distribution of a variable

Tags: python, random, probability

I have got a following problem.

Let's assume that we have a data frame with few variables. Morover one variable (var_A) is a probability score - its values ranges from 0 to 1. I want to sample rows from this data frame in a way that it will be more probable to pick a row with higher value of var_A - so I guess that I have to draw from an empirical distribution of var_A. I know how to implement edf function of var_A as it's suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42541421/how-to-make-a-sample-from-the-empirical-distribution-function) but I have no idea how to use this distribution for sampling rows.

Can you please help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [numpy.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) to sample in this manner:

```
import numpy as np

num_dists = 4
num_samples = 10
var_A = np.random.uniform(0, 1, num_dists)

# ensure var_A sums to 1
var_A /= np.sum(var_A)

samples = np.random.choice(len(var_A), num_samples, p=var_A)

print('var_A: ', var_A)
print('samples: ', samples)
```

Sample output:

```
var_A:  [ 0.23262621  0.02990421  0.22357316  0.51389642]
samples:  [3 0 0 2 0 0 2 3 3 2]
```